# dotplot in ggplot with vertical and horizontal categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a dotplot in `ggplot2` with categories on both the vertical and horizontal axes similar to this image:

[image]

Below, you can find my try at implementing this through `ggplot2`:

```
# load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# create toy data frame
df <- data.frame(type=c("A","B","C","D"),
                  trait1=c(1,1,0,0),
                  trait2=c(1,0,1,0))

# convert data to long format 
melt_df <- melt(df)

# my try at dotplot
ggplot(melt_df, aes(x=type, y=value, group=variable)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center') +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  coord_flip()
```

Could you kindly help me better replicate the image above using the toy dataset that I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plain old `geom_point` for presence/absence:

```r
ggplot(melt_df, aes(x = variable, y = type, color = factor(value))) +
  geom_tile(fill = 'white', color = 'black', size = 1) +
  geom_point(size =  10) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c('D', 'C', 'B', 'A'), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('white', 'black'), guide = 'none') +
  scale_x_discrete(position = 'top', expand = c(0, 0), name = 'Trait') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your incredible answer--you are a wizard! May I kindly ask how to control the size of the tile rows and columns? For example, how would I narrow the `trait` columns such that the dots are closer to edges?

Comment: The best way to do this is to shrink your plotting window @Mike

Comment: It took me a long time to figure it out, but another solution to changing the size of the tile is to use `coord_ratio(ratio = 1)`, where `ratio` takes the `y/x` argument